# Large sql dump to be importend into Oracle Express database

Tags: sql, oracle, import, database-connection, dump

can you plese give an advice on how to import into Oracle Express database an large sql dump (over 6 GB). Oracle Express is designed to deal with such a large import because when I try to import via

```
@/path to file.sql
```

I'm getting all kind of errors regarding the size of import and the database connection is interupted.

Regards,

Comment: I thnik the maximum database size that can be used in Oracle XE is 5GB. https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17781_01/server.112/e18804/storage.htm#ADMQS185

Comment: Actually, it is 11GB of user data now (http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/sql/11g-xe-quicktour-498681.html).

Comment: As of "6 GB" you mention, is that size of the DMP file? If so, and if export was done with the COMPRESSION parameter set, then this might grow above 11GB, which means that you're most probably out of luck and will have to use Standard Edition instead (which isn't free).

Comment: The export file output is of type sql, only sql statemnts of size 6GB maybe I'm lucky :-)

Comment: Ah, so it wasn't exported by Data Pump (or the original EXP utility), but - what? Bunch of INSERT INTO statements? A CSV file? It might help if you posted some of those errors you got.

Comment: I have tried via sql plus using exp command however I got some error like: "LRM-00108: invalid positional parameter value 'v "due to some special character used in password string.

Comment: can you please tell me how to output the log to a file when I try to run the sql statements (ddl and dml statements). Somthing like: @/path to file.sql LOG="<path to log file>" ?

Comment: Use SPOOL command, available in SQL*Plus. More info here: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14357/ch12043.htm